# need sort complex list by position specific element

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Can I use `sort()` function instead of this code to sort this list

```
private static void sortL1Descending(ref List<List<Object>> L1)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < L1.Count; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < L1.Count -1; j++)
        {

            if (Convert.ToInt32(L1[j][1]) < Convert.ToInt32(L1[j + 1][1]))
            {
                List<Object> temp = L1[j];
                L1[j] = L1[j + 1];
                L1[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Can I use` did you try to use? What happened? Did you face any issues?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Sort(Comparison<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__) and supply your own comparison:

```
private static int CompareListItems(List<Object> x, List<Object> y)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(y[1]).CompareTo(Convert.ToInt32(x[1]));
}

private static void sortL1Descending(ref List<List<Object>> L1) 
{
    L1.Sort(CompareListItems);
}
```

Comment: @joodahmed care to share it?

Comment: thanks a lot I change compare with capital C and  done successfully

Comment: @joodahmed stupid typo, sorry about that. Thanks for noticing!